# Regex for word not followed by asterisk

Tags: php, regex

i need a regex (for php) matching any 1 or 2 characters that start with a `+` and end not with a `*`.

So far i got this one: `/\+\b\w{1,2}\b/` which finds `+a3` but also finds `+a3*` as the asterisk is seen as after the word.

In a String like `+find +in +me*` i only want to find the `+in` but not the `+me*`.

I tried with `/\+\b[\w\*]{1,2}\b/` but that does not seem to make any difference.

```
preg_replace($regex,'','+do+find +in +me*'); //expected result: '+do+find +me*'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
/\+\w{1,2}\b(?!\*)/
```

`(?!\*)` is a negative lookahead that assure a `*` doesn't follow the two character.

The `\b` isn't mandatory between `\+` and `\w`.

**Edit according to comment:**

> This matches the "+2c" in "whatever+2c" what would i need to change that it wont match this but only matches for "whatever +2c" or "+2c whatever"

Use this one:

```
/(?:^|\s)\+\w{1,2}(?:\s|$)
```

According to comments:

```
/(?<=^|\s)\+\w{1,2}(?:\s|$)/
```

Comment: This works thanks - i think i only tried `(!\*)` but not with the questionmark. Thanks for the explanation and additional remarks.

Comment: This matches the "+2c" in "whatever+2c" what would i need to change that it wont match this but only matches for "whatever +2c" or "+2c whatever"

Comment: Now it cuts out all my spaces.

Comment: When i usw it with preg_replace($regex, '', $string)

Comment: @Tarsis: Sorry, I don't get you. Please edit your question with some sample strings and expected result.

Comment: See my edit example. Your Solution did cut out all the spaces as it finds "+in " instead of "+in". I did work around that problem now by replacing with one space " " and then cutting out double spaces in a second step.